# Environment variable in Javascript (Gulp)

Tags: javascript, build, environment

I have a **local development** machine and a **test server**.
Now I have an APP_ID that's being used in Javascript. I've been looking into ways that they kan differ on my local machine and on the test server.

#### Using Gulp

With gulp it's possible to add a flag on the command line:

```
gulp build --env=production
```

That way I can get the correct APP_ID from a file.
**The only issue is with this approach I need to run my build on the server, at this moment I run gulp locally and upload the changes to my server**

Is it okay to build on the server? Are there other ways to use environment variables in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to not build on the server but build locally and then deploy to the server using one of the many deploy solution (es. deployer.org for php). Normally javascript NPM packages put build output even in GIT repository ready for use in other projects or for deploy.

For more info on how to use env variable in node (gulp run over node) see this [page](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)

For example in linux you can set env variable with export

app.js :

```
console.log(console.log(process.env.foo))
```

Then try

```
> export foo=app1

> node app.js
```

Res:
    app1

Then try

```
> export foo=app2

> node app.js
```

Res:
    app2

This is valid only if you run your code server side on node (ex on gulp).
If you are developing a client side library and you want to create different builds that targets different enviroments you have to instruct gulp to do so. [In this case this is a guide that can help you](https://www.freshconsulting.com/how-to-organize-your-gulp-js-development-builds-for-multiple-environments/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand how I can make sure for example on my test server, the app_id = 2, and locally the app_id = 1, because if I build on my local machine, it will be 1 either way..

Comment: update answer, you have to set env variable on server not on the command line that you use to launch gulp

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can I read this server environment variable straight in my javascript? Or do I need to build it in? Because I have in 4 js files a reference to that variable..

Comment: Node runs on the server, obviously my (client) js can't read those.. Do you recommend a find and replace in my Javascript files once I build with Gulp? Or are there better ways to go about this?

Comment: Update the answer to clarify node vs client side